# Kafka Topic - filter and dispatch messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

### Background

Our software solution collects data ("events") per customer.
Some of the customers (a small fraction ~3%) ask to get this data into "their systems" (they need to pay for this service).
A target system where we need to send those events might be:

1. AWS S3
2. Azure Storage
3. Splunk
4. DataDog
5. *More target systems to come in the future..*

All target systems above have well known Kafka Connect Sink connectors so the idea is to use those connectors in order to export the data.

### Possible Solution

1. All customer events goes to one "input" topic
2. Custom software consumes messages from the Kafka "input" topic
3. The software looks at the message attributes and based on one of the attributes value (lets call it *customer_id*) decide if the message should be dropped or published to anther Kafka topic named '<*customer_id*>_topic'.

The destination topic will probably be part of a **different cluster**.
I understand this can be easily done using Kafka Streams.

Note that I am aware of the thread [Disperse messages in Kafka stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091920/disperse-messages-in-kafka-stream)

My question is - can it be done using Kafka Connect and SMT?
I am looking for a "managed" solution and since our Kafka run in AWS MSK I dont need to manage the Kafka Connect cluster. With Kafka Streams I will have to install my software on EC2 / ECS - isnt it

Comment: AFAIK, SMTs allow to filter messages, but I don't think that "dynamic routing" is supported? -- Why do you want to use Connect instead of Streams?

Comment: With smt you can alter the topic as well. If I can have a connector with src = Kafka and sink =  Kafka I could do that with SMT. With Kafka connect my code is hosted in the Connect cluster while with streams I need to come with my JVM

Comment: I have edited my question - adding more details that I believe might help

Answer (score 2):

> The destination topic will probably be part of a different cluster. I understand this can be easily done using Kafka Streams

Kafka Streams can/should only write to the same cluster. It cannot guarantee delivery to others.

---

For sending data to other clusters, MirrorMaker would be a starting point.

As you might know, `RegexRouter` can rename the topic, but it cannot pull out dynamic fields from the record and rename the topic - you'd need to write your own transform for this.

You should be able to also use the `Filter` transform to inspect/drop events, but out-of-the-box this only will work on top-level fields, not nested ones.

---

---

Overall, I find having one topic name "per id" a bad design, assuming you might (eventually) have tens to thousands of ids.

Alternatively, managing tens to thousands of clusters "per customer" (or, at least sectioning off clusters with quotas "per client", although not sure how multi tenancy would work with duplicated topic names) might be difficult, too, but that's basically what MSK or Confluent Cloud are doing.

Comment: thanks. I have edited my post and I think that clarify the picture.

Comment: Thanks, thats more clear. From a SaaS/PaaS perspective, running connectors for clients might not be the best idea. Neither would having one Kafka cluster for all customers and then one topic per "customer ID". For example, MSK or Confluent Cloud aren't using one cluster for all their users. Instead, you could harden your Kafka cluster endpoints and distribute security keys and ACLs for the customers to consume their own topics and write to wherever they want, using separate "customer clusters", and they pul from there rather than you having your own write access to their target systems.

Comment: As far as I understand, you suggest that the customers will consume the data as they wish from kafka. This is not an option from product management perspective. We need to "put" the data in the final destination. Now that you are aware of the constraints - what do you think is the best option to use the "power" of Kafka Connect?

Comment: But you are okay writing to S3, for example? So, just write there for the clients that support that, and they can use lambda triggers on their own to be notified of new data, and process accordingly.

Comment: We don't need to notify them. We just need to put the data. Consuming the data is under the customer responsibility. About the number of topics - as I said , only a small fraction of the customers will use this service. So if we will have 100K customers I assume we will have about 3K topics. What do you think?